# Generating JSON with multiple joins without duplicates in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql

I have a simple product store schema

```
    CREATE TABLE optgroups (
      id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
      title VARCHAR(22) UNIQUE NOT NULL CHECK (title <> '')
    );
    CREATE TABLE options (
      id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
      title VARCHAR(22) UNIQUE NOT NULL CHECK (title <> ''),
      optgroup_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES optgroups(id)
    );

    CREATE TABLE products (
      id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
      title VARCHAR(125) UNIQUE NOT NULL CHECK (title <> '')  
    );

    CREATE TABLE products_opts (
      id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
      price REAL NOT NULL CHECK (price >= 0),
      product_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES products(id),
      option_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES options(id),
      UNIQUE (product_id, option_id)
    );

insert into optgroups (title) values ('Size'), ('Color');
insert into options (title, optgroup_id) values ('XS', 1), ('S', 1), ('Red', 2);
insert into products (title) values ('Product 1'), ('Product 2');
insert into products_opts(price, product_id, option_id) values (10, 1, 1), (34, 1, 2);
```

And trying to generate a JSON array like this:

```
[
   {
      "product_id": 1,
      "optgroups": [
         {
           "title": "",
           "options": [
             "title": "",
             "price": 0
           ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Using multiple with-queries and json_agg's but receiving duplicates.Googling didn't give any comparable ideas whereas it should be a very simple query.Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First get all of the columns you will need for the json document:

```
with prod_data as (
  select p.id as product_id,
         og.title as ogtitle,
         o.title as otitle,
         po.price as oprice
    from products p
    join products_opts po 
      on po.product_id = p.id
    join options o 
      on o.id = po.option_id
    join optgroups og
      on og.id = o.optgroup_id
),
```

Aggregate the individual `options` using `jsonb_build_object()` and `jsonb_agg`:

```
 aggopts as (
  select product_id, ogtitle, 
         jsonb_agg(
           jsonb_build_object(
             'title', otitle, 'price', oprice
           )
         ) as options
    from prod_data
   group by product_id, ogtitle
)
```

Aggregate again for the `optgroups`:

```
 aggogrps as (
  select product_id, 
         jsonb_agg(
           jsonb_build_object(
             'title', ogtitle, 'options', options
           )
         ) as optgroups
    from aggopts
   group by product_id
)
```

The main query aggregates all of the json rows to return the final array:

```
select jsonb_agg(
         to_jsonb(aggogrps) order by product_id) 
  from aggogrps;
```

[Working fiddle here.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cdYzN6BhBahBDA5aJ82a4j/0)